# What should be in the columns of the roles table for acl9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acl9

Probably a stupid question but I am pretty close to getting acl9 implemented. Just a little unsure what the data should look like in the roles table:

```
id | name  | authorizable_type | authorizable_id | created_at | updated_at 
---+-------+-------------------+-----------------+------------+------------
```

I assume name would be "admin" and such.

I'm not certain what `authorizable_type` and `authorizable_id` are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of the `authorizable_type` and the `authorizable_id` map the `authorizable_object'. Hope this helps usually if you are creating a roles table in your application your migration should look like the following:

```
class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :roles, :force => true do |t|
      t.string   :name
      t.string   :authorizable_type
      t.integer  :authorizable_id
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :roles, :name
    add_index :roles, [:authorizable_id, authorizable_type]
    add_index :roles, [:name, :authorizable_id, :authorizable_type], :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    remove_index :roles, [:name, :authorizable_id, :authorizable_type]
    remove_index :roles, [:authorizable_id, :authorizable_type]
    remove_index :roles, :name
    drop_table :roles
  end
end
```

Comment: OK, are the values arbitrary? i.e. authorizable_type = all authorizable_id = 1 or something...

Comment: @isea not that I know of. I don't seem to understand why you would need to set values for the `authorizable_type` and `authorizable_id` Also have you looked at the github page for acl9 https://github.com/be9/acl9. Furthermore you should consider using CanCan as acl9 isn't being continually authored. Worth checking out https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Comment: Not sure about [David](/users/529640/david)'s comment here, his answer mentions the reason for the `authorizable_*` fields, and his comment says he doesn't know why they're there. Anyway, I've added some explanation in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, version 1.2 of [acl9](https://github.com/be9/acl9) ships with a generator for the migration needed for the roles table (as well as a few other goodies), see `bin/rails g acl9:setup -h` for more details.

Secondly, to explain these fields, Rails has a feature called polymorphic associations ([read more about it here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Polymorphic+Associations)), which allow you to associate one model with any other model.  acl9 uses this feature to enable to you apply a role on any other model you wish, in acl9 terminology we call those other models *"objects"* ([read more about that here](https://github.com/be9/acl9/wiki/Role-Subsystem#object-model)). All you need to do is include the `acts_as_authorization_object` call in your model and that allows you to do something like this:

```
user.has_role! :admin, school
```

And that user has the `:admin` role for that `school` (and only for that particular school). As per the polymorphic association feature the `authorizable_id` will contain the primary key of that school from your DB, and `authorizable_type` will contain the class name `"School"`.